# create URL that loads website page then scrolls to spot in embedded Google Doc on that page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, google-docs

I have a website ([www.hpaspart.com](http://www.hpaspart.com)) that serves as a document repository.

I need to create a URL that loads a specific website page and then auto-scrolls to spot on that page's embedded Google Doc. The Google Doc is embedded using iframe.

As a sort of example...Below is a link to a page that has an embedded Google doc, and if the user manually scrolls down and clicks the Table of Content item named "Board Meetings" it will scroll down (within that iframe) to the location that was bookmarked (bookmarking was done in the google doc and not on the webpage) but leave the main page in tact.  - https://www.hpaspart.com/5.php

So that works really well. I would like to try and automate the above, but do so with a single URL.  I know the below URL does not work, but I am providing it as an example for what I am trying to do.

What would be great, is to have a single URL that I could post anywhere online such as something like this:  https://www.hpaspart.com/5.php#h.2lfnejv

and it would load https://www.hpaspart.com/5.php and then auto scroll down (within that iframes embedded google doc) to the bookmarked heading referenced with #h.2lfnejv

I know if you use the full google url (https://docs.google.com/document/d/e/2PACX-1vRVMhnKUAuVRVkoDnLxgmQ_IHxFXRLb7o2e0mjoO9ys09hWAVIYUSd78SyQYMrhtroBEBktHrw9kO8A/pub?embedded=true#h.2lfnejv) it will load to that bookmarked heading, but im wanting the user to load to our webpage first and then it stay on that page and scroll down to that referenced location within the embedded Google Doc.

I hope that is clear enough to convey what I am trying to accomplish.

EDIT:  I was not sure if I can post an answer to my own question, but here is what I ended up trying, and it seems to work like I was hoping.

With my  tag of my webpage I did the following:

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/document/d/e/2PACX-1vTd50JlsOLteHC8OYNZZtKsBF86orp71LgBTAReAQ1i7Z2GdeNDIflKmGrRQXtEqDh-I4KPDY8XgXWW/pub?embedded=true#id.u3n2svvb636e" width="850" height="1000" frameborder=0 style="width:100%;"></iframe>
```

Notice that I added #id.u3n2svvb636e to the end of the src url that I used to embed the google doc. Originally, i was trying to add #bookmark=id.u3n2svvb636e to the end of that URL because that is how it shows up if you load the google doc directly and inspect the link of the bookmark.

So in any case, I created a page 183_policy.php with the above embedded url and used that link to place in another google doc, so that when that link is clicked it will load my page and scroll down to the bookmarked location.

Now the only problem i have is that when you click that link within that google doc, it pops up a warning that it is trying to take you to an external domain and makes you allow or go back.

Comment: Is this how you [published](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/183965?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop#zippy=%2Cembed-a-document-spreadsheet-or-presentation) your Google Docs and embed the URL to your website?

Comment: yes, At the top, click File and then  Share and then Publish to web.
In the window that appears, click Embed. Click Publish.
Copy the HTML in the text box and paste it into your site or blog . The document shows up just fine on my website, so that much works fine. Just hoping to achieve the rest of what I posted about :-)  @Serenity

Comment: Thanks for confirming on how you published the Google Docs to web Joseph. As for the error you are seeing after embedding the bookmarked URL, is this the [error message](https://ibb.co/nPv09wB)? If yes, try to use incognito or other browser.